# Questions about predictions in sacred texts

Tags: discussion

There have been several questions along the lines of “are values of important constants in the Bible”.

Would it be within the spirit of the site to treat these as X Y problems in that the X (underlying) question is “does this textual feature of an ancient text demonstrate a supernatural contribution and therefore show that some particular deity (or not particular alien) exists”?

Why else ask about pi in an ancient text? Usually X Y questions are not answered by answering the Y question.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is an answer to your question, or more just sharing your frustration.

> There have been several questions along the lines of “are values of important constants in the Bible”.

Maybe we should be tagging them - preferably with tags that include other ancient texts.

I see three categories, but am open to suggestions:

- Did this ancient opaque poetry explain some scientific fact/invention that wasn't discovered by Europeans for many years?
- Did this ancient opaque poetry spookily predict this later event, Nostradamus-style (i.e. postdiction)?
- Is there a steganographic message hidden inside this ancient text?

My frustration is that I *want* to answer these latter questions with rants showing:

- how many different potential algorithms there are (including Gematria and Bible Code)
- how many different verses there are to choose from
- how many versions of the documents there are to choose from
- how many messages could be extracted that would count as a hit
- how this is *not* evidence to support any major religion, because those theories do **not** predict that secret messages would be encoded in their sacred texts; in fact, generally the opposite.
- Even if it were considered evidence to support a major religion, the fact that other texts can be similarly mined means that the evidence is self-contradictory.

However, a key part of this site is that personal rants are not acceptable. We need to find references. Some of the systems (e.g. the Bible Code) have plenty of skeptical sources, but others do not. [I am not happy with the current answers to the [latest](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53659/are-the-mathematical-constants-e-and-%cf%80-encoded-in-the-bible) of these questions because they do seem too close to lightly-referenced personal rants. I am hoping some better answers will appear.]

But coming back to your question: Generally, if you answer the actual question, we then give an amount of leeway to also address the implications of the claim. So, show that the algorithm *does or doesn't* encode the first 5 digits of π and then show why that doesn't mean anything.

I don't think you are suggesting that you answer the question about Bible codes with a proof or disproof of the existence of God, but just in case: We consider non-empirical religious claims off-topic here. (Also, is this really the best venue to publish a world-changing proof?)

Comment: Maybe my question is “is it acceptable to answer this type of question with - ‘you are asking about a particular encoding/prediction presumably to establish that the document is written/inspired by a specific deity and that is off topic here independent if the specific encoding/prediction of the question.’ ”